# How to add search function code used for "search bar" inside Onclick of "search button" in android

Tags: java, android, search, button, filter

I have 2 activities, in 1st activity there is an "keyword" and "search" button, based on the keyword given related items should be displayed in the second activity in listview form, but just to test i hv placed search bar on top of the listview and coded for it, and this works fine, now the issue s i want to move "search function code" in 2nd activity inside onclick of "search" button.

here's my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    final EditText searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //get the LayoutInflater for inflating the customomView
     //this will be used in the custom adapter
     inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


  final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Creating JSON Parser instance
                final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url = null;
                    String slug = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url);
  //                System.out.println("the map is title "+map.get("title"));
         //title2.add(map.get("title"));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   

                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }


              //searchResults=OriginalValues initially
                searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(songsList);

         // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);   

             list.setAdapter(adapter);


             searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //get the text in the EditText
                    searchString=searchBox.getText().toString();
                    textLength=searchString.length();
                   searchResults.clear();

                   for(int i=0;i<songsList.size();i++)
                   {
                   playerName=songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();
                  System.out.println("player name "+playerName);
                  if(textLength<=playerName.length()){
                  //compare the String in EditText with Names in the    ArrayList
                         if(searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0,textLength))){
                    searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));
                    System.out.println("the array list is "+songsList.get(i));
                    adapter=new LazyAdapter(Home.this, searchResults);   

                     list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us put it this way. What you are doing now is--> you are getting data from the `webservice` in one activity and displaying the entire data in a `listview`. You added just a search functinality on the presented listview itself.

Your requirement is --> You should have a search button in the `first activity`. When it is clicked, you should show the related result in `second activity`. For this, you need to just pass the keyword which has been entered by user to the next activity with the help of `putExtras() through intents`. Then you make a call to `webservice` based on the search keyword rather than bringing a generic result. If this is not exactly what you wanted, just edit your question with more clarification, so that there would be chances of having my answer edited.